# How to preload textures in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, textures, sprite-kit

I have a few frames of animations on my node, and the first time I play the animation it lags, fps drops. Each next time is fine and dandy.

How do I preload the textures to make it work smooth?

I have this method to run when I load the game:

```
- (void)load
{
    self.animationFrames = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"exp1"], [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"exp2"],
                             [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"exp3"], [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"exp4"], [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"exp5"], [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"exp6"], [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"exp7"], [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"exp8"], [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"exp9"]];
}
```

And this method to play animation:

```
-(void)playExplosionAnimation
{
    self.size = CGSizeMake(250, 250);
    SKAction *animation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:self.animationFrames timePerFrame:0.1];

    [self runAction:animation completion:^{
        self.hidden = YES;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should create a [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) and use [**`SKTextureAtlas`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTextureAtlas/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKTextureAtlas/preloadWithCompletionHandler%3a) methods:

```
– preloadWithCompletionHandler:
+ preloadTextureAtlases:withCompletionHandler:
```

Here is what documentation says about this:

> Sprite Kit creates a background task that loads the texture data from
>   the atlas. Then, Sprite Kit returns control to your game. After the
>   texture atlas is loaded, your completion handler is called.
>
> If you need to preload multiple texture atlases at once, use the
>   **`preloadTextureAtlases:withCompletionHandler:`** method instead.

Comment: I'm experiencing a fps drop when preloading texture atlas, even though I verified in Instruments that this work is being done on a worker thread. I've also tried and wrapped it in an `async` block of a global dispatch queue, which doesn't help. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?